# Vuejs / Vue-auth Token is removed from localStorage in IE and Edge works in Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, jwt

Using VUE 2 and the plugin vue-auth (https://github.com/websanova). For whatever reason in IE and Edge the auth token is removed from localStorage on page refresh however in Chrome, FF everything just works and the token isn't removed.

I have been developing in chrome and am approaching a product launch. Was testing in other browsers and then got hit with this near the end of the development phase. Using their docs i am basically setting it up without any real changes.

```
Vue.use(require('@websanova/vue-auth'), {
  auth: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer.js'),
  http: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x.js'),
  router: require('@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x.js'),
  refreshData: {enabled: false},
});

Vue.auth.login({
        method: 'post',
        data: {email: payload.email, password: payload.password, rememberMe: true},
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log('error happened');
        console.log(error);
      })
```

Open IE, go to page, login, view localStorage default_auth_token is present.
Hit F5
User gets logged out.
Vuew localStorage and default_auth_token is gone.

Exactly the same in IE.

I am not doing anything custom with their plugin other then disabling the refesh token option since we don't use them.

I know this might be a long shot looking for a fix here but i have already tried using the github issues (https://github.com/websanova/vue-auth/issues/309) to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I… HATE… IE…

If an cookie has a domain of localhost (doesn't have three dot domain, such as `foo.bar.com`) then IE and Edge just let it fall through without an error. Cookie is not saved and you have no idea why.

```
function setCookie (name, value, timeOffset) {
  var domain = this.options.cookieDomain();
  var expires = (new Date((new Date()).getTime() + timeOffset)).toUTCString();
  if (domain === 'localhost'){
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; Expires=' + expires + ';Path=/;';
  } else {
    document.cookie = name + '=' + value + '; Expires=' + expires + ';Path=/; Domain=' + domain + ';';
  }  
}
```

This took me all day to trace through this plugin but now I actually understand how it all works. I am normally a backend python developer so this was enlightening.